# Multiple nested jQuery Ajax Calls possible Bug?

Tags: jquery, ajax, json, post

On my current project I am using the Google Feed API to get mixed JSON/XML data for a feed. As I want to parse this data on my server before it gets shown to the user I made the following concept.

Client requests JSON/XML Data from Google API via AJAX -> Data is send to my Server via AJAX Post Request (xml_receiver.php writes a cache file) -> Server sends back a parsed JSON Response (json_sender.php loads the cache file) -> jQuery on cliendside puts all data in HTML Context.

The code I have is working like a charm but when I want to debug with FireBug it keeps telling me that the POST Request to xml_receiver.php and also the GET Request to json_sender.php failed.

It's really weird as xml_receiver is definitly receiving the data and json_sender.php is sending the correct output. (Checked 100%!)

PS:The reason why I cache the data with a "trs_id" and not let xml_receiver.php print the JSON data is that jQuery doesn't seem to load the response from xml_receiver.php when the POST finishes.

Here is my jquery code:

```
// JSON Loader Client-Side

$.ajax({

    url: 'http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/services/feed/load?v=1.0&num=10&output=json_xml&q=%Here goes my RSS URL%',

    success: function (data) {

            console.log("JSON Data received, starting Transmission");

            var xml = data.responseData.xmlString; // Get XMLString from JSON Data
            var trs_id = makeid(); // Create a random ID that will be used for transmission

            // Transmit received JSON to Server with data and ID

            $.ajax({
                type: 'POST',
                async: false,
                url: 'http://myserver.com:3333/feed_loader/xml_receiver.php',
                data: {
                    trs_id: trs_id,
                    xml_data: xml
                },
                success: function () {
                    console.log("Transmission to server OK!");
                },
                error: function (error) {
                    console.log("Transmission to server Failed!");
                    console.log(error);
                }
            }); 

            // Get cached and prepared Data back from Server

            $.ajax({
                dataType: 'jsonp',
                url: 'http://myserver.com:3333/feed_loader/json_sender.php?trs_id='+trs_id,
                success: function (data) {
                    console.log("Parsed JSON Data received!");
                    $(data).prependTo('#xml_content'); 
                },
                error: function (error) {
                    console.log("Receiving parsed Data Failed!");
                    console.log(error);
                }
            });

    },

    error: function (data) {

            console.log("Error while loading JSON Data from Google Feed API");

            data = JSON.stringify(data);            
            // Transmit received Error to server    

            $.ajax({
                type: 'POST',
                url: 'http://myserver.com:3333/feed_loader/error_receiver.php',
                data: {
                    json_stream: data,
                },
                success: function (data) {
                    console.log("Error Data was transmitted to Server!");
                }
            });         
    },

    dataType: 'jsonp'

});
```

});

This is what Firebug puts in the console window

JSON Data received, starting Transmission feed_test.html (Zeile 13)
POST http://"myserver":3333/feed_loader/xml_receiver.php 200 OK 49ms jquery....min.js (Zeile 5)

Transmission to server Failed! feed_test.html (Zeile 32)
Object { readyState= 0 , status= 0 , statusText= "[Exception... "Failure"...d :: line 5"  data: no]" } feed_test.html (Zeile 33)

Receiving parsed Data Failed! feed_test.html (Zeile 47) 
Object { readyState=4, status=200, statusText="success"}

Comment: Are your requests being affected by [SOP](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Same_origin_policy)? (i.e. is the initial page on `http://myserver.com:3333` as well?) If you are, you can't make a POST request, unless you're using CORS (which you haven't enabled). If you aren't, why are you using JSONP? Are you emitting a valid JSONP response?

Comment: Why don't you use the [Google API PHP Client](http://code.google.com/p/google-api-php-client/) instead of requesting the feed, send it to your server, request the result...

Comment: @Matt, SOP shouldnt be a problem because the client code is going to run in a Android WebView and I enabled the setAllowUniversalAccessFromFileURLs(); in the JAVA code so SOP is bypassed. Also I am receiving the data, I see the response in the Network tab of fireburg where the response contains the data which my php outputs (both scripts). Maybe its a bug with Firebug, when I run the code on my device LogCat doesn't output any WebConsole Errors.

Comment: @Andreas, I can't use the PHP API as proxy because there would be too many request going on from the Clients using the application. It's better when the data is fetched from the Client.

Comment: One request from the server + one from the client against three from the client?

Comment: You are using jsonp dataType but didnt defined the callback for it. It seems like jQuery received the response but was not able to parse it.

Comment: And what is the purpose of async:false in the request to xml_receiver.php? It actually freezes the browser.

Comment: @Andreas, more like this: 10000 Requests from my Servers-IP to Google or 10000 Requests from different Client-IPs to Google ;)

Comment: @claustrofob, because when I do it async the following ajax call to the json return script executes before the server has received the data from the first call. I tried it with the callback but not differece. I googled the Error "nsresult: "0x80004005 (NS_ERROR_FAILURE)" which is thrown by firebug and it seems like its a problem with Firefox...